# add empty cell in dynamic twig table

Tags: php, twig

Hi I've got the following array

```
Array
(
    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [immobile] => 3
            [interno] => 1A
            [condomino] => Giuseppe Rossi (P)
            [Tabella generale] => Array
                (
                    [spesa] => 187.50
                    [millesimi] => 250.0000
                )

            [Tabella scale] => Array
                (
                    [spesa] => 125.00
                    [millesimi] => 250.0000
                )

        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [immobile] => 3
            [interno] => 1A
            [condomino] => Francesco Rossi (Co-P)
            [Tabella generale] => Array
                (
                    [spesa] => 187.50
                    [millesimi] => 250.0000
                )

            [Tabella scale] => Array
                (
                    [spesa] => 125.00
                    [millesimi] => 250.0000
                )

        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [immobile] => 3
            [interno] => 1A
            [condomino] => Alessandro Rossi (I)
            [Tabella generale] => Array
                (
                    [spesa] => 0.00
                    [millesimi] => 250.0000
                )

            [Tabella scale] => Array
                (
                    [spesa] => 125.00
                    [millesimi] => 250.0000
                )

        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => 8
            [immobile] => 5
            [interno] => 1B
            [condomino] => Alessandro Rossi (P)
            [Tabella generale] => Array
                (
                    [spesa] => 375.00
                    [millesimi] => 250.0000
                )

        )

)
```

And I need to convert it into a table using twig, this is what i've achieved so far

[image]

But i need to achieve this instead:

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
  <table class="table border-top-0 border-bottom small">

    <thead>
        <tr class="border-left-0">

          {% for titolo in ripartoPreventivo|first|keys|slice(1) %}
            <th class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase text-14">{{titolo}} </th>
          {% endfor %}

          <th class="font-weight-bold text-uppercase text-14"> Totale</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

      {% for sub_array in ripartoPreventivo %}
          <tr>
            {% for value in sub_array|slice(1,2) %}
              <td class="font-weight-bold small">{{ value|raw }}</td>
            {% endfor %}

            {% for value in sub_array|slice(3) %}

                <td class="font-weight-bold small">€ -{{ value.spesa|raw }} <span class="small text-muted"><strong>(mill. {{ value.millesimi|raw }})</strong></span></td>

            {% endfor %}

            {% set sum = 0 %}

            {% for value in sub_array|slice(3) %}
              {% set sum = sum + value.spesa %}
            {% endfor %}

            <td class="font-weight-bold small"> € -{{ sum|number_format(2, '.', ',') }}</td>
          </tr>
      {% endfor %}


    </tbody>



  </table>
```

As you can see from the pictures I need to add an empty cell if the dynamic key in the array doesn't exist, instead with my code it put the total where the empty cell should be, any help? many thanks

Comment: Isn't it possible to access your values by keys instead of indexes? Is it because you want to keep it "generic" with the loop over the `<td>` items? If not, I would print the `<td>` items manually as they are directly representing some different data. Or you could loop over the data before the Twig template and fill the missing values with `&nbsp;` so that the empty cells display correctly with a border.

Comment: Hi @PatrickJanser thanks for your answer I need to keep it generic because it is a dynamic array of keys,values so the number of <td> is not always the same

Comment: What I don't understand is that you say the data is generic, but you are actually accessing some parts of the array with your `slice(1,2)` and `slice(3)`, `value.spesa`. For this reason, I thought that accessing the fields by name was more logical than by index (which moves if you have missing entries). If you access it by key then you can do `{{ sub_array.interno|default('') }}`

Comment: Yes, sorry I didn't explain it correctly the first four keys (id, immobile,interno, condominio) are always called (id, immobile,interno, condominio) what is dynamic is the other keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well same as you printed the keys to use them as headers, you can use those keys to output the data

**Do note:** This will only work if the structure of the data remains the same, meaning you only use an array to store the info about `spesa` and `millesimi`

In the snippet below I use the test `iterable` to determine whether the value is an array, based on that the code assumes, if it's an array the keys `spesa` and `millesimi` *are present*.

If you have any other array based values you would need to perform some extra checks

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        {% for key in ripartoPreventivo|first|keys|slice(1) %}
            <th>{{ key }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    {% for row in ripartoPreventivo %}
    <tr>
        {% for key in ripartoPreventivo|first|keys|slice(1) %}
        <td>
            {% set value = row[key]|default('&nbsp;') %}
            {% if value is iterable %}
                € -{{ value.spesa|raw }} <span class="small text-muted"><strong>(mill. {{ value.millesimi|raw }})</strong></span>
            {% else %}
                {{ value|raw }}
            {% endif %}
        </td>
        {% endfor %}
        <td>
            500
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/kvs33w)

---

Just an extra FYI:

Keep in mind that it is possible not all keys will be present in the table as you are using `ripartoPreventivo|first|keys|slice(1)`. This would mean if the first row in the set doesn't have the key `Tabella Scale` present, it will never be shown in the table!

Comment: Hi @DarkBee I've tested your solution and works fine, it is exactly what i was looking for. Ialso discovered the iterable function. I've accepted your answer

Comment: Hi is there a solution to fix the problem if first row in the set doesn't have the key?

Comment: See the answer below, you should need to restructure the data in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do this before rendering your twig. It's adding empty data as the index  *Tabella scale*. If the index exists, so the row isn't affected by the code

$data is your initial array

```
$initial = [
    'spesa' => '',
    'millesimi' => '',
];
foreach($data as $item) {
    if(!isset($item['Tabella scale'])) {
        $item['Tabella scale'] = $initial;
    }
}
```

EDIT :

Based to the comments, I would suggest you to do this (not the cleanest)

```
$modele = [
    "id" => '',
    "immobile" => '',
    "interno" => '',
    "condomino" => '',
    'Tabella generale' => [
        'spesa' => '',
        'millesimi' => '',
    ],
    'Tabella scale' => [
        'spesa' => '',
        'millesimi' => '',
    ]
];
$data = [
    [
        "id" => 10,
        "condomino" => '20',
        'Tabella generale' => [
            'spesa' => '100',
            'millesimi' => '25',
        ],
    ],
    [
        "id" => 22,
        "interno" => '15',
        'Tabella scale' => [
            'spesa' => '100',
            'millesimi' => '25',
        ],
    ],
];
//add all fields from model to all data
foreach($data as $key => $item) {
    //to add fields, use a simple merge
    //be careful of array_merge order
    //if array_merge($item, $modele), your values will be erased
    $new_item = array_merge($modele, $item);
    $data[$key] = $new_item;
}

//reorder based on model keys
$reordered = [];
foreach($data as $row) {
    $item = [];
    #loop over your model keys to have model's order
    foreach($modele as $key_model => $modele_value) {
        #add to your new ordered item at the index of the model, your current value
        $item[$key_model] = $row[$key_model];
    }
    $reordered[] = $item;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your replay, the key 'Tabella scale' is dynamic and is not always called 'Tabella scale' the same for the other keys

Comment: @pippo: I personnaly find @MorganTartreau's solution intelligent. In some way, if your data is generic it must reflect a certain model so should have some default values, such as an empty value. You could loop over all items first to create the model (list of existing fields for all the items). Then loop a second time over this data to set the missing values to `'&nbsp;'` or `''`.

Comment: Hi PatrickJanser yes it make sense the only problem with code posted by MorganTartreau is that it checks if 'tabella scalse' is isset but I don't always have a key called 'tabella scale' as these keys are dynamic also in other scenario it could be the key 'tabella generale' that doesn't have any values so how can I apply MorganTartreau code dynamically?

Comment: This is why I propose you first loop over all items in order to create the *model* which represents the list of all the existing field names. Then, with the second loop over the items you check that each field name is set. If it isn't then you set it to the empty value.